# Evaluation order of logical ANDs and ORs

Tags: javascript

I've got two expressions in the debugger watch (at the same time):

`item.isSelected() === true`: `false`

And at the same time:

`(item.isSelected() === true) && !(item.workflowStatusCode.toUpperCase() === "INRV") && (item.productStatusCode.toUpperCase() !== "ACTV") || (item.workflowStatusCode.toUpperCase() === "INPR")`: `true`

Why the second one evaluates to true when first is false?

**ADDITION:**

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

> Short-circuit evaluation
>
> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
>   for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> *false && anything* is short-circuit evaluated to false.

... it kinda implies that once first expression is evaluated to `false` the rest should have been skipped... I am still not clear what the rules are behind all this.

Comment: Apparently `item.workflowStatusCode.toUpperCase() === "INPR"` is evaluating to `true`, and it’s being ORed with the other part of your expression, so the overall expression is `true`.

Comment: So they are being evaluated left-to-right, where each evaluated pair becomes the result for the next evaluation
? Or it has to do with precedence as Matt Ball suggests? (if so, how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence can be viewed like this.

`NOT` higher than `AND` higher than `OR`

This means that:

```
A && !B && C || D
```

Evaluates like this:

```
( (A && (!B)) && C ) || D
```

The order of evaluation is then:

1. `!B`
2. `A && {1}`
3. `{2} && C`
4. `{3} || D`

Therefore if `D` is `true` nothing else matters and the expression evaluates to `true`.

As an aside, if you put `D ||` at the beginning then lazy evaluators will ignore the rest if `D` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks. I must have been staring at this too much. My original expression is missing the parentheses around the two OR-ed expressions. I asked my question thinking I have them. Of course it woudl evaluate to true without them. Brain cramp...

Answer (score 7):

[`||` has lower precedence than `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), so it's almost certainly the case that this is `true`:

```
(item.workflowStatusCode.toUpperCase() === "INPR")
```

Comment: As for a simpler example, `false && 'anything' || true` is `true`

Comment: So if && has higher precedence, why isn't it evaluated first? I.e. I am not arguing that's the case, just trying to understand this better. Is it the precedence or the order of evaluation?

Comment: @G.Stoynev **precedence** determines where the implicit `( )` are in the expression.

Comment: Could you show the implicit `( )` based on precedence? Or point me to some reference?